# Событие при прокрутке конца списка select

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Доброго времени суток.

Вот наткнулся на такую задачу,как определить конец списка select при прокрутке?

А именно я хочу реализовать такую штуку. У меня имеется список

```
<select class="select_listUser" name="user_list[]" multiple="">
<option value="0">Text_1</option>
<option value="0">Text_2</option>
<option value="0">Text_3</option>
<option value="0">Text_4</option>
<option value="0">Text_5</option>
<option value="0">Text_6</option>
</select>
```

Хочу чтобы при прокрутке списка до конца срабатывал обработчик,который будет добавлять в конец списка еще несколько option.

Не получается  получить конец списка.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так работает в chrome, последний элемент - `$t.children().last()`;

```
$('.select_listUser').scroll(function(e){
    var $t=$(this);    
    if ($t.height()+$t.scrollTop()-$t.prop('scrollHeight')>0) return;
    add_rand_opt($t);    
});

function add_rand_opt($t) {
    $('<option>',{text: Math.random()}).val(Math.random()).appendTo($t);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/bYs3d/

Comment: Спасибо огромное, ты мне очень помог.

Comment: Использую ajax, чтобы при прокрутке до конца списка срабатывал ajax и погружал еще элементы.
    var path = "/cabinet/sro/ajax.php?ajax=Y";
    var currentPage = 1;
    $('.select_listUser').scroll(function(e){
        var $t=$(this);
        if ($t.height()+$t.scrollTop() - $t.prop('scrollHeight')>0){
            return
        }
        console.log("Конец списка");
           $.get(path, {PAGEN_1: ++currentPage}, function(data){
                $(".select_listUser").append(data);
                $(".select_listUser").append(data);
           });
            e.preventDefault();
    });

Comment: вам надо обработчик события тормознуть, до отработки асинхронной функции. (флаг выставить)